# Index on partition after LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql

I have an `InnoDB` table that contains data for a number of years historically and going forward into the future. I need to regularly update the table to add data from a 3rd party source as it becomes available.

Therefore, I have partitioned the table by year (p2004... p2018)

The table is also indexed on a number of fields.

To update, I am doing the following:

> (1) TRUNCATE PARTITION p2018
>
> (2) LOAD DATA INFILE ... (a file containing only data for 2018) ...

The definition of the table makes it clear that that the 2018 data is only placed in partition p2018 (which I've verified by the timestamp on the raw data files).

My questions are: Is the data that is placed in the p2018 indexed upon the completion of (or during) the LOAD DATA INFILE command? Or do I need to issue another command to have the data in p2018 indexed? And if so, is the command

`ALTER TABLE tablename REBUILD PARTITION p2018`

the right command?

I spent about 20 minutes googling (incl. StackExchange) but couldn't find good guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

As the [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
   [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    ....
```

You just need to mention the partition name something like this :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'p2018.csv'
INTO TABLE tbl_year
PARTITION 'p2018'
...
```

Tell us if you need more information.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The question isn't "how do I make sure data is loaded into a specific partition?" The question is "after I load the data [into the partition where it automatically goes, which is indeed the correct one] using LOAD DATA INFILE, **do I need to take another step to make sure the indexes are also created?**" If somehow this answer addresses the indexes in some way, please clarify.

Comment: He is doing a rebuild partition after the Load data. I was answering that he doesn't need to do that. Not sure I have understood the question right but with the code given, i think it's the answer